# The type or namespace name 'Ioc' does not exist in the namespace 'GalaSoft.MvvmLight'

Tags: .net, mvvm-light

I have source code of an WPF application that was designed with MVVM pattern via MvvmLight library. The application has been developed by another developer and now I must support it and add some features.

So now my problem is I cannot build the application. My VS2012 shows a weird compile-time error at the ViewModelLocator class:

> The type or namespace name 'Ioc' does not exist in the namespace 'GalaSoft.MvvmLight' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

...though the project has the reference to GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras library which contains this namespace along with SimpleIoc class used by ViewModelLocator class. Besides that VS even highlights SimpleIoc class and don't highlight Galasoft.MvvmLight.Extras import as error one in uses section...

The application is built against .NET 3.5 and I use the same versions of libraries as the previous developer did.

Please advise what can be a solution for this? Probably anyone met this problem?

Thanks in advance,
Max

Comment: Are you referencing GalaSoft.MvvmLight library in the main project where your library is referenced?

Comment: Yes, I am. GalaSoft.MvvmLight library is referenced by the main project as well.

Comment: The issue solved accidentally by installing MvvmLight library and cleaning the VS solution... But it's hard to find out what exactly helped to solve this. I succeeded with only one of two machines I have.

Answer (score 0):

Add GalaSoft.MVVMLight.Extras because Ioc is present in this library...

Comment: Please read the question carefully:
"...though the project has the reference to GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras library"

Comment: Sorry, for inconvenience. Have you checked the path of all GalsSoftLight references. Are these present same location and for same .Net Framwork.